# MTP sync on LG Spectrum --- kill with extreme prejudice

Tags: mtp

I have an LG Spectrum, running ICS, and I always keep the USB Connection Type on Charge Only. Lately, for some evil reason, whenever I connect the USB cable to a computer, it bloody ignores my setting and decides to do Media Sync (MTP) instead.

I've searched for (and will continue to search for) ways to prevent this, but I've not found much, and what I did find didn't apply to my situation. (E.g., I couldn't Stop MTP in Running Apps, because it wasn't there.)

I don't know the MTP is, but I want it off my phone completely. I don't want the blasted sync. Ever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**`MTP`** stands for *Media Transfer Protocol*. Its honestly better than *Mass Storage* mode because the memory card does not need to be unmounted on the phone for the PC to transfer data.

If you want to disable it, switch your connectivity to **`MSC`** mode first then enable **charge only**. `MTP` is a passive protocol that is why it cannot be turned off when it is set by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By "switch to MSC," I'm guessing you mean Mass Storage? I tried that, in a couple of different sequences, the most recent being: Switch to Mass Storage, connect, see that it's mounted as an external drive. But then it switches back to MTP.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it being a passive protocol, and that's why I can't turn it off? 

I don't know how it got turned on in the first place. That plus the fact that the setting changes on its own after I set it back the way I want it is what's got me really worked up.

Good to know that it doesn't have to unmount the SD card. That will be handy next time I actually to want to connect to my laptop. Right now though I'm just irritated that it's doing exactly what I told it not to do, and I don't know what the side effect of that is. What's it syncing with what?

Comment: As far as I know, it does not have side effects. As for the syncing, the PC side is doing that. You have to disable whatever LG software you have from your PC from starting up at boot time. I recommend CCleaner's startup manager.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've used CCleaner before. I'll look into that, although I've more or less gotten used to it syncing, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything harmful. Just paranoid I guess. :)